# How to calculate BitRate for a VBR mp3 without downloading the entire file?

Tags: c#, streaming, mp3, duration

I want to get the information of the duration for a remote mp3 file at the beginning of its downloading. I can get the frames at first but doesn't know which must be read, Xing or VBRi.

How can I get this information by reading the tags?

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
waveOut.Play();
long offset = from;
ms.Position = 0;
byte[] decBuffer = new byte[50 * 1024];
while (true)
{
   if (paused)
   {
      waveOut.Stop();
      bwProvider.ClearBuffer();
      break;
   }
      lock (LockObj)
      {
         byte[] readed = Helper.ReadStreamPartially(localStream, offset, 100 * 1024, orders);
         if (readed == null)
            continue;
         ms = new MemoryStream(readed);
      }
      Mp3Frame frame;
      try
      {
         frame = Mp3Frame.LoadFromStream(ms);
      }
      catch
      {
         continue;
      }
      if (frame == null)
         continue;

      int decompressed = decompressor.DecompressFrame(frame, decBuffer, 0);

      bwProvider.AddSamples(decBuffer, 0, decompressed);

      if (Helper.IsBufferNearlyFull(bwProvider))
          Thread.Sleep(500);

      offset += ms.Position;

 }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9046492/1070452

Comment: Maybe this helps you - https://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/frame_header.html and http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/mpeghdr.htm

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196011/how-to-read-xingheaders-and-vbriheaders-from-mp3-files-using-taglib-sharp

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but if anyone else needs it...

This CodeProject [**article**](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8295/MPEG-Audio-Frame-Header) has a lot of good formation about MP3 header.

- Find the XING header's start position.
- The 8th byte onwards is an integer of `total frames` (*if exists* will be 4 bytes, Big endian).

Each MPEG frame gives a constant amount of samples per frame, determined by sampling rate, regardless of total *bytes-in-frameX*. You can estimate with a calculation like :

```
durationVBR = single_frame_time * total_frames;
```

Where...

```
single_frame_time = (SampleRate / SamplesPerFrame) * 1000;
```

The constants for `SamplesPerFrame` are :

**MPEG-1**

- Layer I   =  384 samples.
- Layer II  = 1152 samples.
- Layer III = 1152 samples.

**MPEG-2**

- Layer I   =  384 samples.
- Layer II  = 1152 samples.
- Layer III = 576 samples.

Comment: Some files have `Info` instead of `Xing`, both of which have the same format. Other files have `VBRI` which is a different format, and some files have none at all. Even when there is a `Xing` or `info`, the next fields are all optional and you have to parse the flags in the 32-bit field to see which are present and to know at which offset they are at.